# Must view disclaimer page first

Tags: web-applications

I am creating a website that I'll call www.test.com to explain my problem.
When people visit www.test.com they are prompted with a disclaimer page which they must accept in order to enter the website.

If someone visited www.test.com/page5 then before they view page 5 they will be diverted to the disclaimer page before they view page 5.  Then they are free to view any pages they like unless they close the browswer down.

My problem is how do I make it so that they are diverted to the dislaimer page first before seeing other pages?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions.

Populate a key in the session on pressing "Ok" after the Disclaimer. Check for that key on every request. If the key is not found, then redirect to the disclaimer page.

An easy way to check for keys would be to use Filters. 

I suggest some basic reading. Try wikipedia on Sessions (Computer Science) or some detailed tutorials like -
[Servlet and session tutorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29)
[Php Sessions tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html)